# How to use Apache httpd as a reverse proxy with Docker Compose and the "whoami" container?

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

I'm trying to set up a Docker Compose environment that includes an Apache httpd server and a "whoami" container, and I want to use the Apache httpd server as a reverse proxy to route requests to the "whoami" container.

Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  httpd:
    image: httpd:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:ro

  whoami:
    image: containous/whoami
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

And here's my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so

LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

ServerName 127.0.0.1
Listen *:80

<Proxy balancer://whoami>
    BalancerMember http://whoami-replica-1:80
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / balancer://whoami
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://whoami
```

When I run docker-compose up, I can access the "whoami" container at http://localhost:8080, but when I try to access the Apache httpd server at http://localhost, I get httpd exited without any logs.

What am I doing wrong? How can I configure Apache httpd to act as a reverse proxy for the "whoami" container in Docker Compose?

Answer (score 1):

`httpd` is exiting because your `httpd.conf` is invalid. You're *replacing* the default `httpd.conf`, which means you need to take care of mandatory configuration like loading an appropriate security module (e.g., `mod_unixd`).

A better approach is to copy the `httpd.conf` from the httpd image:

```
docker run httpd:latest cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf > httpd.conf
```

And then modify it to meet your needs.

---

I was only able to determine the problem by running Apache locally under control of `strace`:

```
$ sudo strace -e trace=write -s 1024 httpd -DFOREGROUND -f $PWD/httpd.conf
write(2, "[Tue Jun 06 06:00:33.356982 2023] [core:crit] [pid 755528:tid 755528] AH00136: Server MUST relinquish startup privileges before accepting connections.  Please ensure mod_unixd or other system security module is loaded.\n", 219) = 219
write(2, "AH00016: Configuration Failed\n", 30) = 30
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Searching for that error message leads to [this 2.2 to 2.4 upgrade documentation](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/manual24/upgrading.html) which among other things mentions the required `mod_unixd` module.

I was not able to come up with any command line invocation of `httpd` that would get it to emit this error in a useful fashion.